# How to force SQL Studio not to use copy-only backups to build database restore script?

Tags: sql-server, restore, ssms

How to force SQL Studio not to use copy-only backups to build database restore script? I want to ommit copy-only backup (because it's not longer available) and force studio to use last full backup (I mean full without copy-only option), which was done earlier of course.

[image: SQL Studio restore wizard]

Comment: I've reported this on the old feedback system, among other places. To the best knowledge, nothing has been done about it, and there's no workaround. The old feedback system is retired. If you care to report it on the new system (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server), pick back here and I'll vote.

Comment: Maybe I should delete such entries from backup history from MSDB? (dbo.backup% tables)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't advice you in any direction regarding deleting data from backup history. As you understand, do something bad in that clean-up code and you might trash SSMSs ability to restore at all (based on history). And, furthermore, it most probably isn't supported. Myself, I wouldn't do it. I'd just bite the bullet an accept that the restore GUI in SSMS sometimes just isn't usable... Btw, when communicating this with others, I often see the attitude something like "Who uses SSMS to do restore in the first place?" or often even harsher. Just as a heads up...